# Learning a binary classifier which outputs probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, svm

When, in general, the objective is to build a binary classifier which outputs the probability that an instance is positive, which machine learning would be the most appropriate and in which situation?

In particular, it seems that Support Vector Machines with Platt's Scaling could be a good candidate, but I read around the web that someone uses Kernel Logistic Regression or Gaussian Processes for this task. 
Is there any evident advantage/disadvantage of one approach against the others?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Listing all potential algorithms you could use for this general task is close to impossible. Since you mentioned support vector machines (SVMs), I will try to elaborate a little on those.

SVM classifiers never really output an actual probability. The output of an SVM classifier is the distance of the test instance to the separating hyperplane in feature space (this is called the decision value). By default, the predicted label is selected based on the sign of this decision value.

Platt scaling basically fits a sigmoid on top of SVM decision values to scale it to the range of [0, 1], which can then be interpreted as a probability. Similar techniques can be applied on any type of classifier that produces a real-valued output.

Some evident advantages to SVM include:

- computationally efficient nonlinear classifiers (quadratic in no. of training instances),
- can deal with high-dimensional data,
- have shown very good performance in countless domains.

Downsides to SVM include:

- data must be vectorized,
- models are relatively hard to interpret (compared to decision trees or logistic regression),
- dealing with nominal features can be klunky,
- missing values can be very hard to deal with.

When you are looking for proper probabilistic outputs (including confidence intervals), you may want to consider statistical methods such as logistic regression (kernelized versions exist too, but I suggest to start with the basic stuff).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any specific drawback about fitting the sigmoid on SVM against native statistical methods, such as logistic regression?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It makes sense to interpret the (scaled) distance to the separating hyperplane as a probability. In the end, logistic regression works similar (= a standard regression result through a sigmoid function).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options here -- none is always going to be better than another in general.

For methods that make specific statistical or structural assumptions about your data, it's always nice to check that your data follows them.

Without knowing anything in particular about your situation, the best answer is "try them all, see what works best".